# Is there a way to 'include' a separate file in /etc/hosts?

Tags: networking, dns, hosts, ip

Is there any way to 'include' another file within the /etc/hosts file? Particularly I want to include a non-protected (`-rw-rw-rw`) file so I can easily edit it in something like TextMate without having to issue `sudo vi /etc/hosts`

I'm on OS X, but as far as I know, this should be relevant in other *nix OSs.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a security risk if it were even possible?

Comment: Probably, but I thought it was worth asking.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/381138/mac-os-x-hosts-file-can-i-include-other-files-with-it

Comment: Great question. My VPN client overwrites my /etc/hosts file when I connect, so this would help me persist custom entries, if it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe there is any way to include other files into a hosts file.

Would it be possible to make `/etc/hosts` group-writable by a group that only includes you (and any other users who need to edit it)?

Answer (score 6):

Keep a `hosts.base` file and then write a simple script to build a complete, combined `hosts` file with that `hosts.base` file and the other files you want to include. You can `cron` it or execute on demand.

Comment: This is how I do it for local development.  I keep a separate file for each project in a specific location, and run a script that combines the base with the project files.

Comment: @bogeymin do you have a snippet of how that script looks like?